# Como recorrer un diccionario renderizado en Django

Tags: django, diccionarios

Alguien me podría ayudar? El siguiente código esta en view.py, en donde qlresultado es un diccionario que contiene el resultado de procesar una  consulta:

```
return render(request, "pruebaBBDD/respuestaConsulta.html", {"qlresultado":qlresultado})
```

Quiero recorrer cada registro del diccionario en respuestaConsulta.html pero no obtengo ningún resultado deseable. Llevo días consultando y no encuentro alguna solución y por me cuenta no entiendo en que me estoy equivocando.

Cuando quiero recorrer el diccionario con el siguiente código, me retorna la tabla vacía:

```
<table>
    {% for res in qlresultado %}
        <tr>
            <td>
            {{res.agenteRes}}
            {{res.timestampRes}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor%}     
</table>
```

También intenté recorrer con el siguiente código el diccionario pero solo me devuelve el último registro:

```
<table>
    {% for key, value in qlresultado.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>
            {{key}}
            {{value}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}     
</table>
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.